# DispatchQueue doesn't behave like serial queue

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-queue

By using following code, I am expecting that every time the func is caled, minimum time between executions will be 3-4 seconds.

But: when I call the `writeData()` 4 times in row, I see that async block executed without waiting for previous call finished.

```
func writeData(){
    DispatchQueue(label: "be.io").asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        print("START :\(Int64((Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0).rounded()))")
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3)
    }
}
...
writeData()
writeData()
writeData()
writeData()
```

Expected output should be something like:

```
START :1611250630000
START :1611250634000
START :1611250638000
START :1611250642000
```

but on execution i get same timestamp (~1 millisecond difference)  for all 4 calls.

```
START :1611250630000
START :1611250630000
START :1611250630000
START :1611250630000
```

What i am doing wrong?

P.S I tried async without delay, no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DispatchQueue(label: "be.io")` will create a new instance every time you call it

> To get as you expect make it an instance var like

```
let mySerialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "be.io")
```

Comment: Confirmed! The issue is in reinitialization of new DispatchQueue on every call. Class instance variable did the trick. Thank you!